# .txt write to .json file batch or php file needed

Tags: php, json, batch-file

i need and search for a result to convert my .txt file to a .json file with that format:

```
{
"id":"12777475756802056",
"typ":"Solo",
"match":
    {
        "rank":"1",
        "playeruserid":"165496871657",
        "playername":"Example Name",
        "kills":"8",
        "points":"224000",
        "killer":"empty", // while firstplace
        "weapon":"empty" // while firstplace
    },
    {
        "rank":"2",
        "playeruserid":"654987654984",
        "playername":"Example Name 2",
        "kills":"4",
        "points":"168000",
        "killer":"Example Name",
        "weapon":"Shotgun"
    }
    ... another players here.
}
```

and my .txt file looks so, yep really bad... with so many spaces and all in one line...: https://pastebin.com/FP0C9BCj

i try this batch to remove the many spaces:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
SET "sourcedir=D:\Users\Raphael\Desktop"
SET "destdir=D:\Users\Raphael\Desktop"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\matchreport.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
(
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 SET "line=%%a"
 SET "line=!line:?=!"
 SET "line=!line:/=-!"
 SET "line=!line::=!"
 SET "line=!line: =;!"
 ECHO !line!
)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

and idk now why can convert this now to a json file, while all informations on one line pro player, and the json format is now:

```
{"1. 5605****11014 Cl***ma  205000 + 19000 ( 8) = 224000"}
```

and sorry this is my first try to convert a txt to a json file have u any idea to convert this? :/

Comment: can you rely on that format? f.e. will there _allways_ be a space here `( 8)` for example?

Comment: @Jeff idk, 95% of the spaces removed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This almost works.  (Requires PowerShell 3.0 or newer, so, Windows 8 or newer.)  It's a Batch + PowerShell polyglot.  Save it with a .bat extension.

```js
<# : batch portion
@echo off & setlocal

set "file=test.txt"

powershell -noprofile "iex (${%~f0} | out-string)"
exit /b

: end batch / begin powershell #>

function Parse-Fields() {
    add-type -as Microsoft.VisualBasic
    $parser = new-object Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser($env:file)

    $parser.TextFieldType = "FixedWidth"
    $parser.TrimWhiteSpace = $true
    $parser.FieldWidths = @(7, 21, 25, 6, 9, 4, 12, 26, -1)

    while (!$parser.EndOfData) {
        try {
            $parser.ReadFields() -join "," -replace "[\(\+\)\.=]" | ?{ $_ -match "\d" }
        }
        catch {}
    }
    $parser.Close()
}

$header = "ID","GameUserId","Name","Rank","Kills","Score","Total","Killer","Weapon"
Parse-Fields | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header $header | ConvertTo-Json
```

Output:

```js
[
    {
        "ID":  "1",
        "GameUserId":  "5605****11014",
        "Name":  "Cl***ma",
        "Rank":  "205000",
        "Kills":  "19000",
        "Score":  "8",
        "Total":  "224000",
        "Killer":  "",
        "Weapon":  "m4"
    },
    {
        "ID":  "2",
        "GameUserId":  "238444****020",
        "Name":  "Ap*******ift",
        "Rank":  "172403",
        "Kills":  "11550",
        "Score":  "3",
        "Total":  "183953",
        "Killer":  "Cl***ma",
        "Weapon":  "m4"
    },
    {
        "ID":  "3",
        "GameUserId":  "92******9515",
        "Name":  "Sw****UK",
        "Rank":  "156259",
        "Kills":  "14900",
        "Score":  "6",
        "Total":  "171159",
        "Killer":  "Ap*******ift",
        "Weapon":  "m4"
    },
    {
        "ID":  "4",
        "GameUserId":  "6583833***132",
        "Name":  "Moc********kap",
        "Rank":  "144805",
        "Kills":  "2000",
        "Score":  "1",
        "Total":  "146805",
        "Killer":  "Cl***ma",
        "Weapon":  "shotgun"
    },
    {
        "ID":  "5",
        "GameUserId":  "621***7360388",
        "Name":  "Ol***r***",
        "Rank":  "135920",
        "Kills":  "6200",
        "Score":  "3",
        "Total":  "142120",
        "Killer":  "Ap*******ift",
        "Weapon":  "m4"
    },
    {
        "ID":  "6",
        "GameUserId":  "189661****980",
        "Name":  "Op*********gon",
        "Rank":  "128661",
        "Kills":  "0",
        "Score":  "0",
        "Total":  "128661",
        "Killer":  "Sw****UK",
        "Weapon":  "m4"
    },
    {
        "ID":  "7",
        "GameUserId":  "6408****79452",
        "Name":  "M********nner",
        "Rank":  "122523",
        "Kills":  "3500",
        "Score":  "2",
        "Total":  "126023",
        "Killer":  "Sw****UK",
        "Weapon":  "shotgun"
    },
    {
        "ID":  "8",
        "GameUserId":  "59060***2163",
        "Name":  "A***g",
        "Rank":  "117207",
        "Kills":  "0",
        "Score":  "0",
        "Total":  "117207",
        "Killer":  "Ap*******ift",
        "Weapon":  "ak"
    },
    {
        "ID":  "9",
        "GameUserId":  "831467****599",
        "Name":  "*********ngstar",
        "Rank":  "112517",
        "Kills":  "0",
        "Score":  "0",
        "Total":  "112517",
        "Killer":  "Ol***r***",
        "Weapon":  "shotgun"
    },
    {
        "ID":  "10",
        "GameUserId":  "34542****7961",
        "Name":  "********Really",
        "Rank":  "108322",
        "Kills":  "5000",
        "Score":  "3",
        "Total":  "113322",
        "Killer":  "[Toxic Gas]",
        "Weapon":  null
    },
    {
        "ID":  "11",
        "GameUserId":  "904****58750",
        "Name":  "******tch",
        "Rank":  "104528",
        "Kills":  "3500",
        "Score":  "2",
        "Total":  "108028",
        "Killer":  "Sw****UK",
        "Weapon":  "shotgun"
    }
]
```

It probably won't take much to massage it to fit your requirements.  I prefer objectifying data over scraping as flat text.  The script first treats the data as a fixed-width CSV file.  Once objectified as CSV data, it's the converted to JSON.  If no one else suggests a better answer, maybe you can use this as a skeleton to build your project.

---

As an alternative, here's a Batch + JScript polyglot that's a bit more efficient than the PowerShell method, although it's longer.  It doesn't suffer the overhead required by the `TextFieldParser()` class, and JScript is just faster than PowerShell in general.  As a bonus, it should work with earlier versions of Windows, as long as IE version 9 or newer is installed (Vista SP2 I think?).  If you're more comfortable with JavaScript, you might prefer this one.

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off & setlocal

set "file=test.txt"

cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" < "%file%"
exit /b

@end // end Batch / begin JScript

var stdin = WSH.CreateObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(0),
    file = stdin.ReadAll(),
    htmlfile = WSH.CreateObject('htmlfile'),
    csvfields = {"ID": 7, "GameUserId": 21, "Name": 25, "Rank": 6, "Kills": 9,
        "Score": 4, "Total": 12, "Killer": 26, "Weapon": null};

String.prototype.clean = function() {
    var val = this.replace(/[\(\)\.\+=]/g, '').replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
    return /^\d+$/.test(val) ? val * 1 : val;
}

htmlfile.write('<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9" />');
var JSON = htmlfile.parentWindow.JSON,
    lines = obj = new htmlfile.parentWindow.Array();
htmlfile.close();

lines = file.split(/\r?\n/g);
lines.splice(0,4);
for (var i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {
    for (var field in csvfields) {
        if (!obj[i]) obj.push({});
        obj[i][field] = csvfields[field] ?
            lines[i].substring(0, csvfields[field]).clean() : lines[i].clean();
        lines[i] = lines[i].substring(csvfields[field]);
    }
}

WSH.Echo(JSON.stringify(obj, null, '    '));
```

Output is similar, just with integer values unquoted.

Comment: ohw nice looked rly good, but i can change some name values this: "Rank   Kills (##)" to "Points"? and i need the kills as one var like "kills":"2" not "( 2)"

Comment: @cryx Use a texteditor and edit your source files to have different headers and/or modify the `$parser.FieldWidths = @(7, 21, 25, 19, 12, 26, -1)`  rojo supplied you a great idea +1, IMO the rest is up to you.

Comment: @cryx I modified the script a bit, adding the `-header` option to `ConvertFrom-CSV`, which also allowed me to split that 19-character column up into 3 columns (since now there's no longer an attempt to duplicate the "Rank" column name).  I also added a regexp removal of parentheses, plus, equals, and dots on the values.  It's closer, but I'm unsure of whether the "Score" and "Kills" header labels need to be switched.

Comment: One question can i change the header value? one example: "Weapon":  "Weapon" to "Weapon":  "from Weapon", or  "Killer":  "Killer" to "Killer":  "Killed by" can i change that? i find no command to change the value on a json with a bat.

Comment: @cryx Did you try just changing the string in `$header` in the PowerShell version or `csvfields = ...` in the JScript version?  That's all that's needed I believe.

Comment: i want the value, not the variable: "Killer (<- not this)": "Killer (<- this value)" @rojo when i change this csvfields = ... its the variable not the value or im retarded? xD

Comment: I excluded the `{ "key": "columnname" }` JSON array element in one of my edits.  Sorry, I didn't know you needed it.  Do you favor the PowerShell script or the JScript script?  You could probably `$csvobj = Parse-Fields | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header $header` then `$csvobj[0].Weapon = "from Weapon"` and `$csvobj[0].Killer = "Killed by"` and finally `$csvobj | ConvertTo-Json` to massage your data.  If you need more help than that, you probably ought to post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Just for yucks, I implemented a regex solution using my [JREPL.BAT utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044).

I assume that the asterisks are an attempt to mask the data, and they don't appear in the actual input. I'm assuming the IDs are strictly numeric. I also assume that there are at least two spaces after each name (which serves to signal the end of the name).

Here is my batch script that uses [JREPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044):

```
@echo off
setlocal
::                      ID      Type
::         1            2       3
set "find1=^Match ID: *(\d+), *(.*?) *$"

::             Rank     ID     Name                     Kills     Points  Killer    Weapon
::         4   5        6      7                        8          9      10        11
set "find2=^ *(\d+)\. +(\d+) +(.*\S)  +\d+ \+ +\d+ \( *(\d+)\) = *(\d+) +(.*?\S)  +($|.*\S)"

set "repl1={\n\qid\q:\q$2\q,\n\qtyp\q:\q$3\q,\n\qmatch\q:"

set "repl2=    {\n"
set "repl2=%repl2%        \qrank\q:\q$5\q,\n"
set "repl2=%repl2%        \qplayeruserid\q:\q$6\q,\n"
set "repl2=%repl2%        \qplayername\q:\q$7\q,\n"
set "repl2=%repl2%        \qkills\q:\q$8\q,\n"
set "repl2=%repl2%        \qpoints\q:\q$9\q,\n"
set "repl2=%repl2%        \qkiller\q:\q$10\q,\n"
set "repl2=%repl2%        \qweapon\q:\q$11\q\n"
set "repl2=%repl2%    },"

set "find=%find1%/%find2%"
set "repl=%repl1%/%repl2%"

jrepl find repl /v /t "/" /x /a /f test.txt | jrepl "," "\n}" /x /inc -1
```

Here is pseudo-fixed "test.txt" input file with asterisks removed (digit or alpha substituted for asterisk). I intentionally added an inner space to some names and weapons just to test my regex.

```
Match ID: 6549999999997461, Solo
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Rank   GameUserId           Name                       Rank   Kills (##)    Total   Killer                    Weapon
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1.   5605999911014        Claaama                  205000 + 19000 ( 8) = 224000                             m4                              
  2.   2384449999020        Apaaaaaaaift             172403 + 11550 ( 3) = 183953   Claaama                   m4            
  3.   929999999515         Swaa aUK                 156259 + 14900 ( 6) = 171159   Apaaaaaaaift              m4            
  4.   6583833999132        Mocaaaaaaaakap           144805 +  2000 ( 1) = 146805   Claaama                   shotgun            
  5.   6219997360388        Olaaaraaa                135920 +  6200 ( 3) = 142120   Apaaaaaaaift              m4      
  6.   1896619999980        Opaaaaaaaaagon           128661 +     0 ( 0) = 128661   SwaaaaUK                  m4            
  7.   6408999979452        Maaaa aaanner            122523 +  3500 ( 2) = 126023   Swaa aUK                  shot gun              
  8.   590609992163         Aaaag                    117207 +     0 ( 0) = 117207   Apaaaaaaaift              ak      
  9.   8314679999599        aaaaaaaaangstar          112517 +     0 ( 0) = 112517   Olaaaraaa                 shotgun                  
 10.   3454299997961        aaaaaaaaReally           108322 +  5000 ( 3) = 113322   [Toxic Gas]                                              
 11.   9049999958750        aaaa atch                104528 +  3500 ( 2) = 108028   Swaa aUK                  shot gun
```

And here is the final result:

```
{
"id":"6549999999997461",
"typ":"Solo",
"match":
    {
        "rank":"1",
        "playeruserid":"5605999911014",
        "playername":"Claaama",
        "kills":"8",
        "points":"224000",
        "killer":"m4",
        "weapon":""
    },
    {
        "rank":"2",
        "playeruserid":"2384449999020",
        "playername":"Apaaaaaaaift",
        "kills":"3",
        "points":"183953",
        "killer":"Claaama",
        "weapon":"m4"
    },
    {
        "rank":"3",
        "playeruserid":"929999999515",
        "playername":"Swaa aUK",
        "kills":"6",
        "points":"171159",
        "killer":"Apaaaaaaaift",
        "weapon":"m4"
    },
    {
        "rank":"4",
        "playeruserid":"6583833999132",
        "playername":"Mocaaaaaaaakap",
        "kills":"1",
        "points":"146805",
        "killer":"Claaama",
        "weapon":"shotgun"
    },
    {
        "rank":"5",
        "playeruserid":"6219997360388",
        "playername":"Olaaaraaa",
        "kills":"3",
        "points":"142120",
        "killer":"Apaaaaaaaift",
        "weapon":"m4"
    },
    {
        "rank":"6",
        "playeruserid":"1896619999980",
        "playername":"Opaaaaaaaaagon",
        "kills":"0",
        "points":"128661",
        "killer":"SwaaaaUK",
        "weapon":"m4"
    },
    {
        "rank":"7",
        "playeruserid":"6408999979452",
        "playername":"Maaaa aaanner",
        "kills":"2",
        "points":"126023",
        "killer":"Swaa aUK",
        "weapon":"shot gun"
    },
    {
        "rank":"8",
        "playeruserid":"590609992163",
        "playername":"Aaaag",
        "kills":"0",
        "points":"117207",
        "killer":"Apaaaaaaaift",
        "weapon":"ak"
    },
    {
        "rank":"9",
        "playeruserid":"8314679999599",
        "playername":"aaaaaaaaangstar",
        "kills":"0",
        "points":"112517",
        "killer":"Olaaaraaa",
        "weapon":"shotgun"
    },
    {
        "rank":"10",
        "playeruserid":"3454299997961",
        "playername":"aaaaaaaaReally",
        "kills":"3",
        "points":"113322",
        "killer":"[Toxic Gas]",
        "weapon":""
    },
    {
        "rank":"11",
        "playeruserid":"9049999958750",
        "playername":"aaaa atch",
        "kills":"2",
        "points":"108028",
        "killer":"Swaa aUK",
        "weapon":"shot gun"
    }
}
```

Comment: EDIT - Fixed source of "Kills" to the parenthesized value.

Comment: Your json is invalid. `match` is an array and should be `[` enclosed `]`. In addition, the `weapon` attribute of `match`'s first object should have the value 'm4' instead of `killer`.

Answer (score 0):

Although primarily a html/xml/json data extraction tool, [Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) can also process raw text with a little XPath/XQuery magic.

I'm using dbenham's pseudo-fixed '*test.txt*' as input

```
Match ID: 6549999999997461, Solo
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Rank   GameUserId           Name                       Rank   Kills (##)    Total   Killer                    Weapon
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1.   5605999911014        Claaama                  205000 + 19000 ( 8) = 224000                             m4                              
  2.   2384449999020        Apaaaaaaaift             172403 + 11550 ( 3) = 183953   Claaama                   m4            
  3.   929999999515         Swaa aUK                 156259 + 14900 ( 6) = 171159   Apaaaaaaaift              m4            
  4.   6583833999132        Mocaaaaaaaakap           144805 +  2000 ( 1) = 146805   Claaama                   shotgun            
  5.   6219997360388        Olaaaraaa                135920 +  6200 ( 3) = 142120   Apaaaaaaaift              m4      
  6.   1896619999980        Opaaaaaaaaagon           128661 +     0 ( 0) = 128661   SwaaaaUK                  m4            
  7.   6408999979452        Maaaa aaanner            122523 +  3500 ( 2) = 126023   Swaa aUK                  shot gun              
  8.   590609992163         Aaaag                    117207 +     0 ( 0) = 117207   Apaaaaaaaift              ak      
  9.   8314679999599        aaaaaaaaangstar          112517 +     0 ( 0) = 112517   Olaaaraaa                 shotgun                  
 10.   3454299997961        aaaaaaaaReally           108322 +  5000 ( 3) = 113322   [Toxic Gas]                                              
 11.   9049999958750        aaaa atch                104528 +  3500 ( 2) = 108028   Swaa aUK                  shot gun
```

```
xidel.exe -s test.txt -e "let $line:=tokenize($raw,'\r\n'),$match:=extract($line[1],'^Match ID: (\d+), (.+)',(1,2)) return {'id':$match[1],'type':$match[2],'match':$line[position()>4] ! (let $obj:=extract(.,'^ *(\d+)\. +(\d+) +(.*?\S) .+\( ?(\d+)\) = (\d+) {3}(.*?\S?.*?)?  +($|.*\S)',1 to 7) return {'rank':$obj[1],'playeruserid':$obj[2],'playername':$obj[3],'kills':$obj[4],'points':$obj[5],'killer':$obj[6],'weapon':$obj[7]})}"
```

or a bit more readable (prettyprinted):

```
xidel.exe -s test.txt -e ^" ^
  let $line:=tokenize( ^
        $raw, ^
        '\r\n' ^
      ), ^
      $match:=extract( ^
        $line[1], ^
        'Match ID: (\d+), (.+)', ^
        (1,2) ^
      ) ^
  return { ^
    'id':$match[1], ^
    'type':$match[2], ^
    'match':$line[position()^>4] ! ( ^
      let $obj:=extract( ^
        ., ^
        '^^ *(\d+)\. +(\d+) +(.*?\S) .+\( ?(\d+)\) = (\d+) {3}(.*?\S?.*?)?  +($^|.*\S)', ^
        1 to 7 ^
      ) return { ^
        'rank':$obj[1], ^
        'playeruserid':$obj[2], ^
        'playername':$obj[3], ^
        'kills':$obj[4], ^
        'points':$obj[5], ^
        'killer':$obj[6], ^
        'weapon':$obj[7] ^
      } ^
    ) ^
  }^"
```

(the end of each line, as well as `"`,`>`,`^`,`|` needs to be escaped with a `^`)

After opening '*test.txt*' we first create 2 internal variables; `$line` and `$match`.
`$line` becomes a sequence of individual lines. `$match` becomes a sequence of the Match ID and the type by extracting this from the first line of the input.

After assigning these 2 internal variables we begin to create the json. The `id` attribute gets the Match ID is value, the `type` attribute 'Solo'.
Next we create the `match` array and start processing line 5 and up. Each line we feed to the `extract()`-function to create another internal variable (dbenham's regex slightly altered). This variable holds a sequence (7 items) of all the individual values we're looking for. And with this variable we finally populate the object, where we assign the `rank` attribute the first item, `playeruserid` attribute the second item, etc.

The output:

```json
{
  "id": "6549999999997461",
  "type": "Solo",
  "match": [
    {
      "rank": "1",
      "playeruserid": "5605999911014",
      "playername": "Claaama",
      "kills": "8",
      "points": "224000",
      "killer": "",
      "weapon": "m4"
    },
    {
      "rank": "2",
      "playeruserid": "2384449999020",
      "playername": "Apaaaaaaaift",
      "kills": "3",
      "points": "183953",
      "killer": "Claaama",
      "weapon": "m4"
    },
    {
      "rank": "3",
      "playeruserid": "929999999515",
      "playername": "SwaaaaUK",
      "kills": "6",
      "points": "171159",
      "killer": "Apaaaaaaaift",
      "weapon": "m4"
    },
    {
      "rank": "4",
      "playeruserid": "6583833999132",
      "playername": "Mocaaaaaaaakap",
      "kills": "1",
      "points": "146805",
      "killer": "Claaama",
      "weapon": "shotgun"
    },
    {
      "rank": "5",
      "playeruserid": "6219997360388",
      "playername": "Olaaaraaa",
      "kills": "3",
      "points": "142120",
      "killer": "Apaaaaaaaift",
      "weapon": "m4"
    },
    {
      "rank": "6",
      "playeruserid": "1896619999980",
      "playername": "Opaaaaaaaaagon",
      "kills": "0",
      "points": "128661",
      "killer": "SwaaaaUK",
      "weapon": "m4"
    },
    {
      "rank": "7",
      "playeruserid": "6408999979452",
      "playername": "Maaaaaaaanner",
      "kills": "2",
      "points": "126023",
      "killer": "SwaaaaUK",
      "weapon": "shotgun"
    },
    {
      "rank": "8",
      "playeruserid": "590609992163",
      "playername": "Aaaag",
      "kills": "0",
      "points": "117207",
      "killer": "Apaaaaaaaift",
      "weapon": "ak"
    },
    {
      "rank": "9",
      "playeruserid": "8314679999599",
      "playername": "aaaaaaaaangstar",
      "kills": "0",
      "points": "112517",
      "killer": "Olaaaraaa",
      "weapon": "shotgun"
    },
    {
      "rank": "10",
      "playeruserid": "3454299997961",
      "playername": "aaaaaaaaReally",
      "kills": "3",
      "points": "113322",
      "killer": "[Toxic Gas]",
      "weapon": ""
    },
    {
      "rank": "11",
      "playeruserid": "9049999958750",
      "playername": "aaaaaatch",
      "kills": "2",
      "points": "108028",
      "killer": "SwaaaaUK",
      "weapon": "shotgun"
    }
  ]
}
```